# Loading testing for sockjs and vertx application

Tags: performance, benchmarking, load-testing, vert.x, sockjs

I have built an application. It has its backend in vertx (java) and I am hitting it from the client using sockJs. I want to do the load testing (benchmarking/performance testing) for this application. I have not done any load testing before. Can someone please help me out, how can it be done? Like, I want to hit the server concurrently with many connections and see when it fails and what can I do to improve it. Here is a basic code

HttpVerticle.java

```
package sockjs;

import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.core.buffer.Buffer;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpServer;
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router;
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.sockjs.SockJSHandler;
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.sockjs.SockJSHandlerOptions;
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.sockjs.SockJSSocket;

public class HttpVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
    static int count = 0;
    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer();
        Router router = Router.router(Vertx.vertx());
        SockJSHandlerOptions options = new SockJSHandlerOptions();
        options.setHeartbeatInterval(20000);
        SockJSHandler sockJSHandler = SockJSHandler.create(vertx, options);
        sockJSHandler.socketHandler(this::myHandler);
        router.route("/myapp/*").handler(sockJSHandler);
        router.route("/myway/*").handler(sockJSHandler);
        server.requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8080);
    }

    private void myHandler(SockJSSocket sockJSSocket) {
        System.out.println("Connection established " + count); //Calls when the connection is established
        count++;
        System.out.println(sockJSSocket);
        //sockJSSocket.handler(this::processMessage);
        sockJSSocket.handler(buffer -> { //everytime a message is received, a reply is sent back in uppercase.
            System.out.println(buffer.toString());
            String reply = buffer.toString();
            reply = reply.toUpperCase();
            sockJSSocket.write((Buffer.buffer(reply)));
        });
    }

    private void processMessage(Buffer buffer) {
        System.out.println(buffer.toString());
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
package sockjs;

import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Vertx server started");
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        vertx.deployVerticle(new HttpVerticle());
    }
}
```

And the client could be like:

```
var sockJsUrl = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sockjs-client/1.1.1/sockjs.min.js";
var head = document.querySelector("head");
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = sockJsUrl;
head.appendChild(script);



var sock = new SockJS("http://localhost:8080/myapp");
sock.onopen = function() {
    console.log("Connection open", sock.readyState);
}

sock.onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log("Message from server");
    console.log(event);
}

sock.onclose = function() {
    console.log("Connection closed", sock.readyState);
}

sock.onerror = function() {
    console.log("Connection error", sock.readyState);
}
```

To be frank, I have no knowledge on performance testing at all. So if someone give me detail, I would be thankful.

Comment: My project is in sockJs and not WebSockets. So how can I use thor for this as the document says that Thor takes only ws protocol?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 3 standalone options:

1. [Gatling](http://gatling.io/) tool - [Websocket](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.0-RC2/http/websocket.html#websocket)
2. [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/) - [Websocket](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/user_manual/conf-sessions.html#websocket)
3. [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) with [WebSocket Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/websocket-testing-apache-jmeter) plugin

If you prefer JavaScript-based solution you could take a look at [Artillery](https://artillery.io/)

And a couple of "usual" recommendations:

1. Don't forget to monitor server-side operating system resources, i.e. CPU, RAM, Swap, Disk and Network usage - any of them can become a bottleneck
2. Run your application under a [profiler tool](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2014/06/java-performance-tuning-tools/) telemetry - it will allow to quicker identify the root cause of the issue if it is related to your application
3. Remember that web/application server default configuration usually is not suitable for high loads, you might need to tweak it somehow in advance

Comment: My application is on SockJs, these tools are all for websockets or socket.io. So how can I use it for sockJs. Please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/observing/thor

Note it's for websocket only, so you won't be able to test performances for the emulations (when websocket is not available in your browser or network).

Comment: My application is on SockJs, these tools are all for websockets or socket.io. So how can I use it for sockJs.